# Insert one object to a many relationship - IOS Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, one-to-many, relationship

I have seen various answers around helping explain adding records in one-to-many relationships but I can't seem to make head or tail of it for my code.

I have got a relationship - Country has many Counties

I am adding Counties to Countries that already exist but can't seem to get a method that will add the County to a Country relationship...

My code is:

```
@class Country, Property;

@interface County : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * last_server_update;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Country *country;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *properties;
@end

@interface County (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addPropertiesObject:(Property *)value;
- (void)removePropertiesObject:(Property *)value;
- (void)addProperties:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeProperties:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

Country.h

```
@class County, Property;

@interface Country : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * last_server_update;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *properties;
@property (nonatomic, retain) County *counties;
@end

@interface Country (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addPropertiesObject:(Property *)value;
- (void)removePropertiesObject:(Property *)value;
- (void)addProperties:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeProperties:(NSSet *)values;

- (void)addCountiesObject:(County *)value;
- (void)removeCountiesObject:(County *)value;
- (void)addCounties:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeCounties:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

In my controller:

```
Country * newCounty;
newCounty = [County createEntity];

// Get Country
Country * relatedCountry = [Country findFirstByAttribute:@"id" withValue:[county objectForKey:@"country_id"]];
                 
newCounty.id = [county objectForKey:@"id"];
newCounty.name = [county objectForKey:@"name"];
newCounty.country = relatedCountry;  // Does not compile
```

I am using MagicalRecord for finders btw

### EDIT

The error
Property 'country' not found on object of type 'Country'

The relationships are setup as

Country

- Relationship: counties
- Destination: County
- Inverse: country
- To-Many Relationship: checked

County

- Relationship: country
- Destination: Country
- Inverse: counties
- To-Many Relationship: unchecked

Comment: You say you're getting a compiler error on that last line... what is the error message? That might help. Also, are you sure you've set up the inverse relationships in your model? Finally, are you sure `relatedCountry` is what you expect it to be? (Add some NSLogs or a debugger breakpoint to be sure.)

Comment: Sorry, the error would have helped... I have updated to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
Country * newCounty;
```

to

```
County * newCounty;
```

;)

Comment: Thank you.  +1,000 to my melonfactor! Can't believe it was something so simple.

Comment: Don't you get a compiler warning on the line `newCounty = [County createEntity]` ?